# How do I web scrape data on an HTML page that only shows up on a mouse hover over parts of a map/image using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the following data from a map on this page: https://a816-dohbesp.nyc.gov/IndicatorPublic/AQHub/explorer.html

[Screenshot of the map I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR7kg.png)

- Groupings by the colors on the map (Low/Medium/High)
- Neighborhood names that show up on a mouse hover

**Question**: How do I figure out which elements to scrape the data from?

When I inspect the map, it points to this HTML code, but it doesn't seem to change when I move my cursor around the map. I can't seem to find an XPath for the text elements showing the individual names that pop up when you hover your mouse over the map. I am trying to use Python (BeautifulSoup and Selenium).

```html
<canvas width="546" height="500" class="marks">
```

Ideally I'd like to end up with a spreadsheet that has the the following information like this:

| Neighborhood | Building emissions | Building density | Industrial Area | Traffic Density |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Midtown-Midtown South | High | High | High | High |

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so please let me know how I might better ask my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could move the mouse around via ActionChains on the canvas, but probably want the data (and not complicating things).

Try: `results = driver.execute_script("return nyccasData")`.